# How can I bring all content to the center of page?

Tags: html, css

I added `margin:0 auto;` in `.wrapper` class for bringing all content to center. I have couple of questions:

1. Is `margin:0 auto;` enough for centering content?
2. How to solve centering problem in my case?

This is my **style.css** file.

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0
}
body {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-family: arial
}
.wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.form_area {}
```

And This is my **index.html** file.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Hello</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Hello</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Hello</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Hello</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="form_area">
    <form action="" method="POST">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>First Number :</td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" name="numOne" placeholder="Input Your First Number">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Second Number :</td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" name="numTwo" placeholder="Input Your Second Number">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calculate">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Working **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/xwdn3a91/)**

Comment: What is your centering problem? Your demo seems fine.

Comment: See very carefully its `.wrapper{width: 960px;margin: 0 auto;}` but content is not center of  `width:960px`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few points to consider..

1. The width of the `.wrapper` that you want to center has to be less than the `.container`. in order to to see a noticable difference. In your example, the width of the wrapper is so wide that it cannot be "*centered*"!. Try setting the width to something smaller maybe like, `400px`.
2. The content that you want to 'center' also matters. Like if you want

   1. To center the text then just use the `text-align:center;` property.
   2. To center each element then make them `display` as `inline-block` and then set the `text-align:center;` property of the parent.
3. If you have applied `float` to the `.wrapper` or any element that you wish to center, then `margin: 0 auto;` **wont work**. Because the `float` disturbs the normal flow of the document and pulls the element out of the normal flow.

As per your comments.

Just Introduce another `div` lets say `.centered` inside the `.wrapper` and encompassing the content to be centered. And assign a smaller `width` to it and set `margin: 0 auto;`. It should center with respect to the `.wrapper` .
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xwdn3a91/3/)

Comment: I want `.wrapper` `div` `width :900px` and `.form_area` `width:500px;` with centering content.Is it possible?

Comment: but it is not properly center of the page width take a look when you scroll horizontally and make screen 900px width then it goes to left side.

Comment: Then dont set the width of the `.wrapper` then it will be centered at all the widths greater than its own.

Comment: Take a look its not properly center of the page http://s7.postimg.org/s06pi4hvv/Capture.png

Comment: @Mujib Yes i understand now.Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Check these two chrome inspector snapshots, http://i.imgsafe.org/afceaf0.png , http://i.imgsafe.org/b749d68.png

Answer (score 1):

It is fine, but maybe your screen resolution is small, change the width to a smaller value to see it

```
.wrapper {width:300px; margin:0px auto;}    <!-- demo width-->
```

Answer (score 1):

```
body { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
.wrapper
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%; 
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0; 
    right: 0;
}
```

or use below code

```
.wrapper
{
   text-align: center;
}
.centered{
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

if your html is like:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="centered">
       ......
       your content
       ......
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: give your wrapper width 70% then tell me what happend.I see when i give 70% then it towards the left.